# How to evaluate json string containing enum value?

Tags: java, json, enums, gson

I have an enum that looks something like this

```
public enum Example {
    EXAMPLE_1,
    EXAMPLE_2,
    EXAMPLE_3,
}
```

I am trying to parse a json string like this:

```
String json = "{\"blah\": \"Example.EXAMPLE_1\"}"
```

I have tried defining a class like this:

```
public class Blah {
    Example blah;
}
```

and using

```
gson.fromJson(json, Blah.class)
```

but it just sets the field to null.  Is there anyway to do this?  I unfortunately can't control the format of the json string so I have to parse it as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default gson will parse enum field without class name. You can customise your own json deserializer for Example enum.

```
JsonDeserializer<?> jd = new JsonDeserializer<Example>() {
  @Override
  public Example deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    String enumStr = json.getAsString();
    String enumVal = enumStr.split("\\."); // etc...
    Example val = ... ...
    //...

    return val;
  }
};

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Example.class, jd).create();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this json

```
String json = "{\"blah\": \"EXAMPLE_1\"}"
```